# How to extracting large amounts of data (more than 100 MB) from Snowflake into CSV

Tags: syntax-error, extract, export-to-csv, large-data

I am trying to export large amounts of data from snowflake into a CSV.  I saw a similar question and the solution given was to “Run the query as part of a COPY INTO {location} command to an internal stage, and then use a GET command to pull it down locally.”

I tried following the guide and ran the following but receives the error, “SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 3 unexpected 'file_format'.”
I am not sure how to fix this or even if the first part of my syntax is correct.  Can someone please help.

```
copy into @my_stage/result/data_ from (select *
from"IRIS"."PRODUCTION"."VW_ALL_IIS_LHJ"
where (RECIP_ADDRESS_COUNTY = 06065 or ADMIN_ADDRESS_COUNTY = 06065) 
   file_format=(TYPE='CSV');
 [ HEADER = TRUE]                                      
    get @%my_stage/result/data.csv/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that you're missing a closing parenthesis.  Try:

```
copy into @my_stage/result/data_ from (select *
from"IRIS"."PRODUCTION"."VW_ALL_IIS_LHJ"
where (RECIP_ADDRESS_COUNTY = 06065 or ADMIN_ADDRESS_COUNTY = 06065))
   file_format=(TYPE='CSV');
 [ HEADER = TRUE]                                      
    get @%my_stage/result/data.csv/;
```

Sorry - I don't have a way to test this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses after the where clause. You opened a parentheses after the first FROM and then another one at the WHERE clause, but you only closed the WHERE parentheses.

Also, AFAIK, you don't need to call a get if the stage was properly set. The copy into command will place it in your stage, you then retrieve it from that stage but you can do this by the normal way of accessing the stage you specified. So if you sent it to a s3 bucket, you'd just access the resource from S3 as if it were any other file.

Lastly, remember there are many useful parameters you can indicate in the FILE_FORMAT, such as Record_delimiter, compression and how to handle nulls.
And remove the last semicolon after csv, that's going to cause another error because HEADER is not a valid instruction on its own.

Also you don't have to put HEADER = TRUE between brackets. Brackets in documentation mean it's an optional parameter.